# Custom javascript button to change body background and font color

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Note: not a duplicated because this is a custom made code and no other answer is answering my question, also because this is only javascript and not Jquery based**

After reading hundreds of other posts and answers I decided to create a simple function instead of complicated/advanced ones, using just javascript. The problem is that I just started to learn javascript yesterday :)

**What I want:**

I want users to click on a single toggle button to turn dark mode on/off without complications in the code but just to save the value in **localStorage** and/or retrieve the chosen values from **localStorage**

The colors are just 2:

Dark mode is: body background #101010 and body font color if #FFFFFF

Light mode is: body background #FFFFFF and body font color if #101010

What I have

HTML

```
<button class="change" value="on">Dark mode is on</a>
<button class="change" value="off">Dark mode is off</a>
#would be nice with a single toggle button
```

Javascript

```
var document.querySelector(".change")
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
if (body[0].style.backgroundColor === "on") {
body[0].style.backgroundColor = "#101010"
body[0].style.color = "#FAFAFA"

} else {
body[0].style.backgroundColor = "#FAFAFA"
body[0].style.color = "#101010"

}
localStorage.setItem("bgColor", body[0].style.backgroundColor)
localStorage.setItem("textColor", body[0].style.color)
})
body[0].style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("bgColor")
body[0].style.color = localStorage.getItem("textColor")
```

What I need

To make it save the chosen colors by the user and remember them with localstorage

To know if it is possible to make the button toggle with the text:
Dark mode is on/Dark mode is off

I created this Codepen with the code
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/gOQMrjX

Comment: Very much a duplicate already of the pretty much the same question you already asked three hours ago, and then deleted again, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76505757/1427878 Why did you delete the original version? Especially since you already got feedback below it, which you are now not even addressing at all, by the looks of it?

Comment: `<button id="change" value="on">`, `<button id="change" value="off">` - IDs _must_ be unique.

Comment: The other question was about changing background but not about dark mode so the code is not the same. But thanks for the short commend before CBroe, it helped me. I did not chose your answers because you never answered but just commented

Comment: _"To make it save the chosen colors by the user"_ - where does the user chose colors here? They don't, they only make the choice dark mode, yes or no - the colors are already specified by you. So instead of setting colors on individual elements via inline style, you should much rather add/remove a class on the `html` element - and all the rest gets handled via your stylesheet.

Comment: I don't know how to do it CBroe. I am just learning. But I changed to class=""change" now

Comment: `if (body[0].style.backgroundColor === "on") {` — If what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71888075/1427878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine now, I just added on to your code.

The selected (mode)colors by the user will be saved in localStorage and retrieved when the page is loaded.  Additionally I updated the CSS to include a `.dark-mode` class that applies the dark mode styles to the body element.

```
html
<button id="toggleBtn">Dark mode is on</button>
```

javascript

```
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById("toggleBtn");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var bgColor, textColor;

  if (body.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
    body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    toggleBtn.textContent = "Dark mode is on";
    bgColor = "#FFFFFF";
    textColor = "#101010";
  } else {
    body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    toggleBtn.textContent = "Dark mode is off";
    bgColor = "#101010";
    textColor = "#FFFFFF";
  }

  body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  body.style.color = textColor;

  // Save the chosen colors to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("bgColor", bgColor);
  localStorage.setItem("textColor", textColor);
});

// Retrieve saved colors from localStorage
var savedBgColor = localStorage.getItem("bgColor");
var savedTextColor = localStorage.getItem("textColor");

if (savedBgColor && savedTextColor) {
  body.style.backgroundColor = savedBgColor;
  body.style.color = savedTextColor;

  if (savedBgColor === "#101010" && savedTextColor === "#FFFFFF") {
    body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    toggleBtn.textContent = "Dark mode is off";
  }
}
```

```
css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: #101010;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfect and is exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your help and I am choosing this answers as correct

Answer (score 0):

Newb here also, buy I'll try to help you.

I suggest using a checkbox. You can use CSS to make a slider button. Follow below what you need with my comments.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('change'); //Get the status os the checkbox
  
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() { //Checks if the status changed
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        document.body.classList.add('dark-theme'); //Uses the dark-theme that is in the CSS file.
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark'); //Saves the "theme" in local storage
      } else {
        document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme'); //Goes back to normal model in the CSS file
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');  //Saves the "theme" in local storage
      }
    });
  
    var savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme'); //When you load the page, it will check which 'theme' is stored. If it is normal, it does nothing, if it's dark, checks the checkbox and uses the dark-theme in CSS.
    if (savedTheme === 'dark') {
      checkbox.checked = true;
      document.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
    }
  });
```

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<label for="change">Dark mode</label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="change">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
```

```
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```